# What is the furthest object from which fermion rays were detected?

Tags: cosmic-ray

What is the furthest object from which non-electromagnetic cosmic rays were detected?

Comment: FYI, this post was flagged as "low-quality" at one point because it's short. I don't think that's true, but could you still add some extra information to make the question even clearer?

Comment: Duplicate on physics SE http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/49999/what-is-the-furthest-object-from-which-fermion-rays-were-detected

Comment: @Aaron This question is too old to migrate and merge, and it is not off topic here. Therefore, that is not sufficient reason to close.

Comment: Anixx, were you hoping to receive a different answer here?